# Why am I getting this error while trying to parse Json from this website's Json API?

Tags: java, json

I am trying to read the Pokemon names from this website's JSON API: http://pokeapi.pokesnipe.de/.

I've tried a few things but I still can't get it to work for the life of me. Here is the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String sURL = "http://pokeapi.pokesnipe.de/"; 

    URL url = new URL(sURL);
    HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    request.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    request.connect();
    
    JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); 
    JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); 
    JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); 
    String name = rootobj.get("name").getAsString();
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

And here is the error I am receiving:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownServiceException: no content-type
at java.net.URLConnection.getContentHandler(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(Unknown Source)
at pokeglass.RetrieveData.main(RetrieveData.java:24)
```

Line 24 reads:

```
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Why mark it as duplicate? There's not even an answer in that thread..

Comment: I just thought I would add that I am using gson to do this. In case that helps answer my question.

Comment: I see an accepted answer  with 5 upvotes that states: _If you don't need to rely on the `content-type` returned by the server, you should use `getInputStream` which doesn't require the content-type to be set._

Comment: Shoot sorry I am new to this website. That resolved the problem.